# how to break ties in rank power bi

Tags: powerbi

I am using rank based on the number of incidents per site, but there are sites where it has the same number of incidents, but I get ties, and I would like to break the tie.

```
Rank_4 = 
IF(
    HASONEVALUE('inci soporte_nuevo'[pb_cod_nom]),
    RANKX(
        ALLSELECTED('inci soporte_nuevo'[pb_cod_nom]),
        CALCULATE(
            SUM('inci soporte_nuevo'[nro_inc])
        ),
        ,
        DESC
    )
)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0PhU.png)

What should I add in the rank_4 measure?

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the help of DAX RANKX, you can see there is an option on how to handle ties:

```
RANKX(<table>, <expression>[, <value>[, <order>[, <ties>]]])
```

So in your case you can simply write Dense as option to RANKX:

```
RANKX(
        ALLSELECTED('inci soporte_nuevo'[pb_cod_nom]),
        CALCULATE(
            SUM('inci soporte_nuevo'[nro_inc])),
            ,
            DESC, Dense
    )
```